# Question on the Feynman's double slit experinment with light source in the middle of slits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, double-slit-experiment

I've been reading Feynman's Lectures on Physics, Volume III on the chapter 1-6 "Watching the electrons". Feynman goes on that we can observe electrons going through the slits if we put a light source between the slits.

> If, for instance, an electron were to take the path via hole 2 that is sketched in Fig. 1-4, we should see a flash of light coming from the vicinity of the place marked A in the figure.

Why is this the case? Feynman speaks on the cause where "electric charge scatter light", however I couldn't find any information about this or to my knowledge. Another issue is that if by putting a light source in the middle of the double slits, doesn't the light from the light source make it difficult, or impossible to see if the intensity of light is strong enough? If that is the case, then how do we detect the flash of light that Feynman is talking about here?

Answer (score 2):

Feynman's double slit setup is a thought experiment designed to show the peculiarity of QM in a simple way. It has not experimentally been conducted in the way Feynman described it, partly because of the reasons you pointed out.

In 2013, [experimentalists have recreated Feynman's experiment](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/15/3/033018/pdf) with some modifications. Here instead of using a light source to tell from which slit the electron went through, they instead control the opening and closing of the slits *by placing a movable mask in front of a double-slit*.

For readers' reference, I have attached the figure OP's been referring to in the question below:

[image]

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thank you.